When, Where and Why to add "Citations" when Identifying a Species?
I am having trouble figuring out when to add citations to my answers.
Recently, I was spammed with 4 notifications saying: 

Consequently, after reading these notifications, I was left in the lurch. And have no idea what to do to fix and remove these banners.
On all of the answers I added scientific names and english ones, as well as providing a high quality photo that matched the species and was from a reputable, committed source.
Okay, so now what? I ended up going through and changing from this:

To this:

Now what? I edited the question and added "citations", how do I fix the banner? Are my citations good enough? Or must I add all my references at the bottom as well?
Please bear in mind that I have answered across many scientific websites and identified hundreds of species in this same way. Across the stackexchange as well. Why am I getting flagged now?
Here are the other answers if you are interested:

Answer Two
Answer Three
Answer Four

To conclude, I would like to apologize if this question was rude or offensive to the site or moderators in any way. I am genuinely confused, and would like assistance. - Thank you

If you are referring to other sources, especially with quotes, you need to let us know where it came from. Leave a link or citation or both to credit the original author.
Same thing with images - let us know where the picture came from.
The banner isn't automatic, if you've fixed your question you can Flag "In need of moderator intervention" and explain that you've added citations and would like the banner removed.
Welcome to Biology Stack Exchange and thanks for helping people identify species!
Here's a guide to help:
https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Ah, that makes a lot more sense! Thank you so much for your help!

@Arrow No problem; I added a link to some help on referencing if you have further questions.

@Arrow In addition - while your IDs seem good and very knowledgeable, you almost never say WHY you think it is the species in question - what features tell you that it is the species you think it is. References are all well and good - you only need to add one and a citation reference for any images, but why is important too.

@bob1 Its been 6 months, my knowledge of citations has greatly improved in my time away from the stack community. I also had started to provide "good" explanations as to "why" I thought this and that. Take my most recent answer for instance (recent being 6 months ago) https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/114738/what-is-this-insect-possibly-a-cockroach/114773#114773

@Arrow Excellent, makes your answers a really valuable source for this community.
